# cygwin error (abnormal exit: exit code=254)

Tags: cygwin

Been trying to cygwin installed and running into problems with some post installs.

The following are failing..

```
-base-files-mketc.sh
-base-files-profile.sh


2017/06/02 14:48:55 running: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh"
      0 [main] bash 2428 fork: child 6752 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1137782 [main] bash 2428 fork: child 1712 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3285408 [main] bash 2428 fork: child 9380 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7435306 [main] bash 2428 fork: child 10776 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
15581306 [main] bash 2428 fork: child 1644 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
2017/06/02 14:49:11 abnormal exit: exit code=254
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You have some program that is interfering with Cygwin, likely an Antivirus but it can be another BLODA. see https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures

Comment: A total uninstall of Norton and a re-attempt at an install had no effect, similar results.  BLODA, I'm not finding a definition???

Comment: look on the same page https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: Ok, found BLODA.. still that doesn't help. Is there an installation log or something that will help me find what is blocking the install? Can this be installled in "safe mode"?

Comment: BLODA = Big List Of Dodgy Apps